# Update inputAccessoryView in SwiftUI (UIViewRepresentable)

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, uitextfield, uiviewrepresentable

I want to display search results above the keyboard with SwiftUI. For this, I made a `UIViewRepresentable` for `UITextField` and set the `inputAccessoryView` accordingly.

Everything is displayed correctly, but the `inputAccessoryView` is not updating.

```
 struct V_ToolbarTextField<Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var title: String
    @Binding var text: String
    var keyType: UIKeyboardType
    
    var toolbarContent: Content
        
    init(_ title: String,
         text: Binding<String>,
         keyType: UIKeyboardType = .alphabet,
         toolbarContent: Content) {
        self.title = title
        self._text = text
        self.keyType = keyType
        self.toolbarContent = toolbarContent
    }
    
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textfield = UITextField()
        textfield.keyboardType = keyType
        textfield.placeholder = title

        let textUIKit = UIHostingController(rootView: toolbarContent)
        textUIKit.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 60)

        textfield.inputAccessoryView = textUIKit.view
        return textfield
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
}
```

This is how I am passing the `inputAccessoryView`'s content:

```
 V_ToolbarTextField("Title",
                    text: $gameNameFilter, 
                    toolbarContent: 
                     viewContainingSearchResults())
```

I've tried binding `toolbarContent` and setting the `inputAccessoryView` in `updateUIView()`. I've also tried creating a Coordinator class and setting the `UITextField`'s delegate to it, hoping to use a `UITextFieldDelegate` function to update it, but I don't know which one and I wasn't able to set the delegate correctly.

Comment: Can u show the code for `viewContainingSearchResults()`

Comment: @cedricbahirwe I've tried it with a simple TextView(), even there the bound text didn't update, so that's not the problem

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get it to work and ditched the `inputAccessoryView` for a `VStack` with the ToolBar at the bottom. I hide it when the keyboard is shown.

```
@State var keyboardOpen = false

VStack {
    
    // everything else...
    
    if (keyboardOpen) {
        V_FilteredGameList(filter: vm.gameName, action: { game in
            vm.setExistingGame(game: game)
            hideKeyboard()
        })
    }
}
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)) { _ in
        keyboardOpen = true
}
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)) { _ in
        keyboardOpen = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling reloadInputViews() on your textfield. Most likely you want to do it on updateUIView function.

open func reloadInputViews() by Apple documentation:
// If called while object is first responder, reloads inputView, inputAccessoryView, and textInputMode.  Otherwise ignored